# Why is my foreground service killed by Android System?

Tags: java, android, service, location, foreground-service

My app is a tracking app where I want to track user location in a service and then display every location in a fragment.
I have a problem with background service: my service is stopped after some minutes (sometimes < 10 minutes, sometimes > 30 minutes).
I start my location service in this fragment and everything goes fine when I use my app.
The problem is when I close (not kill) my app and start something else on my phone (or just block it), after a few minutes my service is stopped and I don't know why.
I show a foreground notification when my service is running but android system still stops it, I notice this because my notification disappear and my app restarts.

Here is my code for the service:

```
public class LocationService extends Service {

private static final String TAG = "LocationService";
public static final String NEW_VALUE_INTENT_ACTION = "service_new_value";
public static final String INTENT_LATITUDE = "latitude";
public static final String INTENT_LONGITUDE = "longitude";
public static final String INTENT_SPEED = "speed";
public static final String INTENT_ACCURACY = "accuracy";
private static final long TWO_MINUTES = 1000 * 60 * 2;
private static final long INTERVAL = 5000;
private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 2000;
private int ONGOING_NOTIFICATION = 1111;

private Location currentLocation;
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = null;

private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

/**
 * Provides access to the Fused Location Provider API.
 */
private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;

/**
 * Callback for changes in location.
 */
private LocationCallback mLocationCallback;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.d(LocationService.TAG, "LocationService ---> onCreate()");
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d(LocationService.TAG, "LocationService ---> onDestroy()");
    super.onDestroy();
    stopForeground(true);
     mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d(LocationService.TAG, "LocationService ---> onStartCommand()");
    startServiceTask();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(LocationService.TAG, "LocationService ---> onUnbind()");
    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}

private void startServiceTask() {
    Log.d(LocationService.TAG, "GpsService ---> Starting ...");

    setServiceAsForeground();

    initFusedLocationProvider();

    Log.d(LocationService.TAG, "MyStartedService ---> Starting ...");


}

private void initFusedLocationProvider() {
    mFusedLocationClient = new FusedLocationProviderClient(this);

    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();

    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);

    mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
            if (currentLocation == null)
                currentLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();

            else if (isBetterLocation(locationResult.getLastLocation(), currentLocation)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged(): Updating Location ... " + currentLocation.getProvider());
                currentLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();
        }
            notifyValueUpdate();
    } }, getMainLooper());
}


protected boolean isBetterLocation(Location location, Location currentBestLocation) {
    if (currentBestLocation == null) {
        // A new location is always better than no location
        return true;
    }

    // Check whether the new location fix is newer or older
    long timeDelta = location.getTime() - currentBestLocation.getTime();
    boolean isSignificantlyNewer = timeDelta > TWO_MINUTES;
    boolean isSignificantlyOlder = timeDelta < -TWO_MINUTES;
    boolean isNewer = timeDelta > 0;

    // If it's been more than two minutes since the current location, use
    // the new location
    // because the user has likely moved
    if (isSignificantlyNewer) {
        return true;
        // If the new location is more than two minutes older, it must be
        // worse
    } else if (isSignificantlyOlder) {
        return false;
    }

    // Check whether the new location fix is more or less accurate
    int accuracyDelta = (int) (location.getAccuracy() - currentBestLocation
            .getAccuracy());
    boolean isLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 0;
    boolean isMoreAccurate = accuracyDelta < 0;
    boolean isSignificantlyLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 200;

    // Check if the old and new location are from the same provider
    boolean isFromSameProvider = isSameProvider(location.getProvider(),
            currentBestLocation.getProvider());

    // Determine location quality using a combination of timeliness and
    // accuracy
    if (isMoreAccurate) {
        return true;
    } else if (isNewer && !isLessAccurate) {
        return true;
    } else if (isNewer && !isSignificantlyLessAccurate
            && isFromSameProvider) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/** Checks whether two providers are the same */
private boolean isSameProvider(String provider1, String provider2) {
    if (provider1 == null) {
        return provider2 == null;
    }
    return provider1.equals(provider2);
}

private void setServiceAsForeground() {
    Log.d(LocationService.TAG, "GpsService ---> setServiceAsForeground()");

    // Prepare the intent triggered if the notification is selected
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationService.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    builder = null;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel("ID", "Name", importance);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), notificationChannel.getId());
    } else {
        builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    }

    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        v.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(500, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
    } else {
        //deprecated in API 26
        v.vibrate(500);
    }
    // Build the notification
    // Use NotificationCompat.Builder instead of just Notification.Builder to support older Android versions
    Notification notification = builder.setContentTitle("MyMovements")
            .setContentText("Running ...")
            .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
            .setBadgeIconType(getNotificationIcon())
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true).build();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION, notification, FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_LOCATION);
    }
    else {
        startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION,notification);
    }
}

private int getNotificationIcon(){

    SharedPreferences settings = this.getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.PREFERENCE,0);
    String icon = settings.getString(MapFragment.NOTIFICATION_PREF, " ");
    switch (icon) {
        case "Walking":
            return R.drawable.walk;
        case "Public Transportation":
            return R.drawable.bus;
        case "Driving":
            return R.drawable.car;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}

private void updateNotification(){
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    String conc = "Running...\n" + "Lat: " + currentLocation.getLatitude() + " " + "Lng: " + currentLocation.getLongitude();
    Notification notification = builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
            .bigText(conc))
            .setContentText(conc).build();
    notificationManager.notify(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION, notification);
}

private void notifyValueUpdate(){
    Log.d(TAG, "MyStartedService ---> notifyValueUpdate()");

    if(currentLocation != null) {
        updateNotification();
        Log.d(LocationService.TAG, currentLocation.getProvider());
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.setAction(NEW_VALUE_INTENT_ACTION);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putDouble(INTENT_LATITUDE, currentLocation.getLatitude());
        bundle.putDouble(INTENT_LONGITUDE, currentLocation.getLongitude());
        bundle.putDouble(INTENT_SPEED, currentLocation.getSpeed()*3.6);
        bundle.putDouble(INTENT_ACCURACY, currentLocation.getAccuracy());
        broadcastIntent.putExtras(bundle);

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    }
}
```

}

I started my service in OnServiceCommand() -> startServiceTask() -> setServiceAsForeground()

I will really appreciate any tips for my code (this is a scholar project and this is my first app, so probably I am doing something wrong).

Thanks to everyone

Comment: welcome to stack overflow :) i've made a few minor changes to your question, removing some irrelevant text and updating some minor spelling mistakes, feel free to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64626887/edit) your question if you're unhappy with my changes, hope you find an answer

Comment: "I notice this because my notification disappear and my app restarts" -- your app may be crashing. Does Logcat give you any clues?

Comment: @a_local_nobody Thanks for what you have done with my question :)

Comment: Maybe it's because Android documentation says : If your app targets API level 26 or higher, the system imposes restrictions on running background services when the app itself isn't in the foreground. In most situations, for example, you shouldn't access location information from the background.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am pretty sure that my app doesn't crash because I have no Logcat error and all the times I have this problem. For example I have succesfull used my app on background for one hour today and everything goes fine, I received all the location and during this hour the notification was always active. I think this problem comes when I have to much app opened or my Xiaomi has low battery.

Comment: @ruben I think this could be the cause of my problem but, for example app like Runtastic or NikeRunning, could stay in foreground for hours and get location information. I want to implement a similar service

Comment: I suspect that the key word there is "Xiaomi". Reportedly, they have very aggressive algorithms for deciding what can and cannot run. You may wish to examine the Settings app and see if you can add your app to a whitelist.

Comment: @CommonsWare I think It too, but if i run my app and Runtastic toghether my app sometimes reports the problem but Runtastic never. So, I want to know how can I emulate something similar without modify settings, of coarse if It Is possible